# How does Ocaml variable scope work?

Tags: ocaml

I'm starting learning Ocaml, using [hickey book](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf), and I'm stuck on Exercise 3.4, part 9

```
let x x = x + 1 in x 2
```

The result of the operation is `3`, but I don't understand why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `let x x = ...` you are defining a function called `x` which binds the name `x` to its argument.

Since you used `let` instead of `let rec`, the function doesn't know its own name, so as far as it knows, the only `x` worth knowing about is the one passed in as an argument.

Therefore when you call the function with `x 2`, it binds the value `2` to the name `x` and evaluates `x+1`, getting `3` as the result.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that a function and an argument could have the same name.

Comment: They can, but obviously you should **never, ever** do this in real code :) (In fact this even works with `let rec` instead of `let`, and has the potential to be even more confusing...)

Comment: It's easier to see why this is possible when you realise that `let x x = e` is just shorthand for `let x = (fun x -> e)`.

Comment: The good thing is that `let rec x x = ...` becomes `let rec x = (function x -> ...)` which obviously is equivalent to `let x = (function x -> ...)`